# I need a VPS on Amazon AWS that can run Chrome and work with files

Tags: vps, amazon-ec2, amazon-aws, windows-server-2008

I am new to working with VPS (I'm a web developer), and **I need a VPS from AMAZON AWS that can run Google Chrome, and download files** (not big files).

Currently I have the free teir of Windoews Server 2008 R2 Base (Currently selected: t2.micro (Variable ECUs, 1 vCPUs, 2.5 GHz, Intel Xeon Family, 1 GiB memory, EBS only) - which I can't do anything there... So I guess I'll have to get myself a paid server.

**Which AMI windows server fits my needs best(the last one I used is Windoews Server 2008 R2 Base)?**

**And whay type of AMI should work for me (currently using the free teir: t2.micro (Currently selected: Variable ECUs, 1 vCPUs, 2.5 GHz, Intel Xeon Family, 1 GiB memory, EBS only)?**

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately questions seeking recommendations for external resources such as web hosts are considered [off-topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site since they often lead to spam and promotional answers, hence the  question marked as duplicate was established.

Comment: @dan Where is the best place to get a recommendation for something like this?

Comment: You could ask in our chat room, but I'm unable to recommend other sites. Good luck.

Comment: @dan Thanks, What chat room is the most appropriate for this kind on issue?